# What to do about these trivial edits? (http → https)

Tags: discussion, support, editing, https

I happened to look back at an old post of mine, and found that it was recently edited by a user with 1 reputation point. The edits were trivial — e.g., in https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1057573/revisions, you can see that a link was replaced by the same link with a small URL difference.

1. Why would someone do this in the first place?
2. Should I just revert these unnecessary edits?

Comment: I spell stuffs wrong all the time n then they edits my posts. Makes me chuckle. Not sure to laugh at how dumb I must look to people or how dumb it is that people care so much. Either way, we are all idiots, and that's worth a laugh or two!

Comment: Some editor has tried to edit a post of mine from 2013, two consecutive days

Comment: @amWhy: Is it the Community User? And are they editing URLs? If so, see the accepted answer (below).

Comment: Kieran No,  the first edit was approved by two users yesterday, but I had the option to reject the edit, and did so.  Today I saw, after the same editor of the same question attempted to make substantial edits, the edit attempt was rejected.  It was a to an answer from 2013! (I had helped the asker to find one, say x= 2, of three roots (cubic polynomial), so that $x-2$ would be one factor, and explained polynomial division, for the asker to obtain a quadratic, to find the other two roots.  The attempted edit deleted half my post, and simply provided the entire answer (all three roots.)

Comment: @amWhy when I get edits like that proposed I just let em through. If the reviewers approve it then it must be a decent edit/improvement, right? :p

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The reviewers also rejected the edits.

Comment: Why would you reverse them?!

Comment: If it had been a registered user rather than an anonymous edit I'd have asked the person why it was done. Sometimes there is a reason that you don't know about.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: If an edit modifies my original intention, I always [attempt to] reverse it.

Comment: Changing http to https modifies your original intention?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: No… all I said was __if__ an edit modifies my intention, I always [attempt to] reverse it. Your comment (especially the interrobang) strongly implied that one should never try to reverse a trivial edit under any circumstances — or at least I inferred that, and hence my clarification.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This was an automatic edit by the [Community](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1) user as part of [the recent network-wide change to https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058). In reality, an SE developer was responsible behind the scenes for this edit (and many [*many*](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/671269/counting-http-https-edits-by-the-community-user) others in the same time period).

The proper course of action is to simply ignore this edit, and all others like it: they were made for a reason.

Comment: So why is it not hidden automatically, if it is just noise?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It is not noise. It is keeping a public record of the evolution of the post. If anything one could say that the edit description isn't clear enough (for example it could contain a link to the Meta Stack Exchange post about the switch to https). But since these edits were entirely silent (as in, they did not bump the posts) this isn't really a big deal, imho.

Answer (score 11):

Here's my answer if the edit were really by a newbie with low rep: let it stand if it's correct.

When I see newbie answers to old already answered questions I'll sometimes comment with a welcome message, then mildly suggests that this particular contribution didn't add much, but that I hoped to see more posts that did. I don't downvote.

I remember that when I was new I wanted to exercise my chance to make everything better here. The fact that I could make (minor) edits made me feel welcome in the community.  After a while I realized those small fixes were unnecessary, and even distracting if they bumped old posts to the front page.

I still fix many typos in question titles - perhaps more than I should.

Edit: Here's a recent example. not from a new user (shortly after I posted my answer): 
https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/17765/revisions

Comment: I totally get that — and I've let lots of those types of edits slide. This time, [not knowing who The Community User was], I was worried that someone was trying to “game the system”, getting reputation for doing things which were neither of mathematical importance nor made the post any clearer/better.

Comment: The Voice of Reason. Thanks for nudging users up the ladder. Thanks for fighting math anxiety. Thanks for fixing titles. It helps searchers and cuts down on duplications.