# What happened on April 2017?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, statistics

I used the [query](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22503) in this answer to see the number of edits per month and I was fairly surprised as April 2017 had $86,444$ edits.

[image: Graph of edits vs time 1]

The graph of edits per day is even more surprising as one day had $55, 073$ edits, though I am unable to pinpoint the exact date! I am vey surprised because referring back to the graph per month, the second most edits in a month was $33, 740$ edits on November 2015.

[image: graph of edits vs time 2]

> Is this a random event or a processing error? Or did something occur so that so many edits took place (retagging, etc)? Or is this a problem in the query?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This, I think, is the move to `https` links, where all the links which point to SE were silently edited in the background from `http` to `https`.

For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/29797/revisions, which points out to the date in question being April 13, 2017.

Comment: Manually sorting the results table confirms that 13 April 2017 was the day in question.

Comment: Related (Math) Meta question : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26287/what-to-do-about-these-trivial-edits-http-%E2%86%92-https